# How can I best post-process underexposed, noisy images taken at 5000 iso?

Tags: photo-editing, noise-reduction, iso-noise, olympus-omd, noise-removal

I'm editing photos but the photographer was quite new and he took photos using Olympus OMD EM5II at 1/400, ISO 5000 and at f3.5 resulting in a underexposed noisy image. (The photos are raw.)

I tried searching youtube and googling on proper noise reduction techniques in Photoshop and Lightroom but it seems the photos are still dirty or look fake.

Can someone suggest a proper way to treat these photos? Or a workaround at least?

Comment: could you post a sample image or part of image. It would be hard to help you because your Q is very general, and also because "photos are still dirty or lools fake" is subejctive

Comment: Does [How to brighten photo taken with low light/fast shutter without worsening noise?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50471/how-to-brighten-photo-taken-with-low-light-fast-shutter-without-worsening-noise) help?

Comment: What was the situation where the photos were taken, and how underexposed are the images? The exposure settings you give should result in reasonably-decent brightness in a typical well-lit interior, and this camera has a modern sensor with the potential to produce great results (even with apparent noise) at ISO 5000. (See e.g. [examples here](https://www.photographyblog.com/reviews/olympus_om_d_e_m5_mark_ii_review/sample_images/).)

Comment: you can probably recover a less-noisy BW image from the green channel, blue is where most of the noise usually comes from.